# Deploying code on a bunch of machines

Tags: software-rec

I have some binaries and code to be deployed to various environments. I currently use pexpect library in python to connect and rsync over sash to sync the code. Currently the method uses push mechanism to deploy. Is there a better way to do this? Is pull mechanism better. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you add more details? What kind of environments? Heterogeneous or not? What code exactly? Mixed hardware architectures? Why sash?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.4/index.html) or [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a [distributed revision control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control_system) like [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29), [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial_%28software%29) etc.

Answer (score 0):

http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/07/murder-fast-datacenter-code-deploys.html

Here's some interesting implementation of Bittorrent protocol for distributed deploy by Twitter guys.